# creating a box with an image

Tags: php, javascript, gd, imagemagick, imagick

I'd like to take an image and turn the corners over to make a box (like a canvas painting)

i have gd library, imagemagick installed on the server and imagick php extension installed.

is it possible? any help appreciated

Comment: I will accept answers I accept, seems pretty logical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> turn the corners over

You're gonna need to explain this a little better. You can overlay a frame onto an image with the GD functions. Check out [imagecopymerge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php)